# Bootstrap jQuery - Issues with empty field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've written some jQuery to validate my Bootstrap forms, however I'm having a few issues.

Firstly, I want a red outline to appear if the user clicks off the input field without typing anything in: [JSFiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/xqwsobmo/18/). In this example I'm using the [Bootstrap Validator plugin](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/), however I want to imitate this effect without using the plugin.

Second, and linked to the issue I just mentioned, the green outline only appears once the user clicks the submit button, thus the user only sees it for half a second or so before they are redirected, making it a little pointless. Again, this would be solved by having an error/success outline appear once the user clicks off the input. If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<form id="auth_form" action="action.php" method="post">

  <div class="form-group has-feedback" name="auth_code" id="auth_code">
    <label for="auth_code" class="control-label">
    Authorisation Code</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="auth_code_input" name="auth_code_input" type="password">
    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon" id="iconBad"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-info" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#auth_form').on('submit', function(e) {
     var auth_code = $('#auth_code_input').val()

     if (auth_code=="") {
       $('#auth_code').addClass('has-error');
       $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
       e.preventDefault();
     } else {
       $('#auth_code').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
       $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
     }
   })
 })
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/xqwsobmo/17/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this updated fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/xqwsobmo/20/](https://jsfiddle.net/xqwsobmo/20/)

Need to add input blur event and validate input

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
   $('#auth_code_input').blur(function(){
      if(!ValidateInput()){
          e.preventDefault();
      }
   });

   $('#auth_form').on('submit', function(e) {
     if(!ValidateInput()){
          e.preventDefault();
      }
   })
 });

 function ValidateInput(){
    var IsValid=false; 
    var auth_code = $('#auth_code_input').val()    
    if (auth_code=="") {
       $('#auth_code').addClass('has-error');
       $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
         IsValid=false;
    } else {
       $('#auth_code').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
       $('#iconBad').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
       IsValid=true;
    }         
     return IsValid;
 }
```

Comment: for some optimal reason you can use a simple function to factorize the answer below and call it in both event `submit` and `blur` so that if there is any change you hope to do it will be done once and you're not supposed to repeat it